# Count columns within joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I really confuse about joins when it comes to be for more than two tables in addition of using functions in select statement!

I've three tables `users`, `data` and `projects`. Each row on `data` uniquely relates to a user of `users` table and the foreign key of `data` table is `uid` column which references to `id` of `users` table.

Wasn't hard up to now? I hope though.

Each project in `projects` table has two column named `starter` and `finisher` both of them references on `id` column of `users` table too and are different from each other.

So what! I wanna fetch data of each user including their `data` and the **number** of `projects` that they started it (as `starter`) or finished it (as `finisher`)

```
select 
    d . *,
    u . *,
    COUNT(p.starter) as starter,
    COUNT(p.finisher) as finisher
from
    users u
        left join
    projects p ON u.id = p.freelancer
        left join
    data d ON u.id = d.uid
GROUP BY (u.id)
```

This query results in all users (as expected) who has been a `starter` or `finisher` or nothing at all (has no corresponding row on `projects`) **But** the count results are not correct! for example user with id `1` has finished *one* project and has started *three* ones but the results show `1` and `1` for both `starter` and `finisher` columns!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining on the wrong field.  This approach summarizes by the `starter` and `finisher` before joining together:

```
select d.*, u.*,
       coalesce(sum(ps.cnt), 0) as starter,
       coalesce(SUM(pf.cnt), 0) as finisher
from users u left join
     (select p.starter, count(*) as cnt
      from projects p
      group by p.starter
     ) ps
     on ps.starter = u.id left join
     (select p.finisher, count(*) as cnt
      from projects p
      group by p.finisher
     ) pf
     on pf.finisher = u.id left join
     data d
     ON u.id = d.uid
GROUP BY (u.id);
```

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 'p.starter' in 'field list'`

Comment: Executes but the results include `1` for both starter and finisher counts! True result should be 3 for `starter` and 1 for `finisher`

Comment: @revo . . . The query was adding up the wrong values -- the id not the cnt.

Comment: I made Sql fiddle but as your last edit, I should say, It works!

Answer (score 4):

Using subqueries you can count the number of times each user has been a `starter` and a `finisher`.

```
SELECT u.id
      ,s.countStarter
      ,f.countFinisher
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT starter, 
           COUNT(*) AS countStarter
    FROM projects 
    GROUP BY starter
) s ON u.id = s.starter
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT finisher, 
           COUNT(*) AS countFinisher
    FROM projects 
    GROUP BY finisher
) f ON u.id = f.finisher
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0ac3/7/0)

Comment: This will generate a cartesian product when a user starts more than one project and finishes more than one product.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not disputing you, but I don't understand what you mean - clearly it didn't work though. Feel free to post the correct answer rather than telling me how to fix though cos I g2g for 10 minutes!

Comment: Let me phrase it differently.  The expressions `count(p.starter)` and `count(p.finisher)` count the non-null values in each column.  If someone started and finished at least one project, then these will be non-null in all rows for that user.  The two counts will produce the same value.

Comment: Right I see what you mean, this answer is complete rubbish but I'll try to salvage it ;)

Comment: @revo Ok so I've updated my answer with something that does work.. it's a lot less clean than I had originally hoped though.

Comment: +1 But I don't have permission on accepting two answers! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what your looking for:

```
SELECT *, id as userid,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    projects
    WHERE   projects.starter = userid
    OR      projects.finisher = userid
    )AS number
FROM users
        LEFT JOIN data
            ON users.id = data.uid
```

I have tested this quickly on my database and it worked like a charm :). Hope it helps